# Suitable components for 2M257 magnetron - capacitors, transformers, diodes and waveguides

Tags: magnetron

I'm looking for recommendations on components suitable for a [2M257 magnetron](http://magnetron.co.kr/english/product/product.htm?mdvn=101&cate=LG%20Electronics&idx=11). Can anyone advise on the values of capacitors, transformers, diodes, and waveguides that would be compatible and efficient for this Magnetron model? Specifically, I'm interested in capacitors with sufficient voltage ratings and capacitance, transformers capable of stepping up voltage appropriately, high-voltage diodes suitable for rectification, and waveguides designed for optimal microwave energy transmission.

Comment: You need to edit your question fairly promptly to make it less like a shopping question or it will be closed.

Comment: What is your power source? Do you want any modulation? How and where will you be transmitting? Are you licensed for such transmission power and mode?

Comment: I would get some more experience before playing around with a 1.5kW magnetron that is powered from 2+ kV and can irreversibly blind you.