# Selection of diode and transformer for a 1500 W magnetron

Tags: component-selection, magnetron

I have a 1500 W magnetron. What diode and transformer can I use for it?

Comment: This sounds very similar to your previous question: [Suitable components for 2M257 magnetron - capacitors, transformers, diodes and waveguides](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/707780/suitable-components-for-2m257-magnetron-capacitors-transformers-diodes-and-w) Consider editing to improve that question, rather than re-asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the transformer from a matching micowave oven, as it needs a defined air gap in the core to function as expected. The silicon diode needs to be at least a 4kV 1A type, or higher depending on the anode voltage of the magnetron.

It's not worth the effort. At best, you don't electrocute and neither microwave yourself or people you like.